# PostgreSQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function to_char(unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy teniendo problemas con esta query en PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT serie,
    ......more fields...
    CASE WHEN fecha1 > SUBSTRING(to_char('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),1,10) THEN 'AL DIA' ELSE 'ATRASADO' END AS estado
    .....
```

El error me lo marca dentro de `CASE WHEN` en `tochar(unknown)`. Acá dejo una captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La función `to_char()` en Postgresql recibe dos parámetros (no uno solo) y tienen que ser del tipo correcto. [Aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html) puedes consultar la documentación.

Comment: Faltan argumentos para la función **to_char** eso es lo que indica el mensaje, intenta con esto ```to_char('2021-10-27 00:00:00','YYYY-MON-DD HH12:MIPM')```

Comment: Ese `1,10)` dos veces, de entrada da un indicio de que la sintaxis está mal (paréntesis mal balanceados). Como te han indicado, fijate en la documentación los parámetros que recibe `to_char`. Por cierto, `fecha1`  ¿es una cadena o un DATE? De ser lo segundo, ¿por qué no comparás directamente por fechas?

Comment: mirando la docu,, tomé este ej. 
to_date ( text, text ) → date
Converts string to date according to the given format.
to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY') → 2000-12-05

en mi caso
to_char('2021-10-27 00:00:00' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

pero me devuelve 
`ERROR: function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique`

gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Porque estás queriendo convertir una cadena a cadena... A no ser que quieras hacer un `to_char` de un `to_date`. A eso también iba mi pregunta con el comentario anterior. _Analizá bien el código que escribís_.

Comment: @rpaillao lo hice así, pero me devuelve `ERROR: function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique`
así lo dejé: `CASE WHEN pu.d1>(TO_CHAR('2021-10-28', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')|| '00:00:00') THEN 'AL DIA' ELSE 'ATRASADO' END AS estado`